# Disable Content Editor for Specific Pages

Tags: php, visual-editor

I know how to block the content editor on a single, specific page but I would like to block it on more than one page.

In the code below if add another page file to the following then everything breaks.

Is there a way to reference more than just the one template file?

Thanks

```
function wpcs_disable_content_editor() {

$post_id = $_GET['post'] ? $_GET['post'] : $_POST['post_ID'] ;

if( !isset( $post_id ) ) return;

$template_file = get_post_meta($post_id, '_wp_page_template', true);

if ( $template_file == 'page-custom-one.php', 'page-custom-two.php' ) {
    remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'editor' );
}
```

}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpcs_disable_content_editor' );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if condition is wrong and generates a syntax error. You need an [logical operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) to check for multiple conditions. Therefore your code should look like the following:

```
if ( $template_file === 'page-custom-one.php' || $template_file === 'page-custom-two.php' ) {
  remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'editor' );
}
```

You could also check for multiple values with the [in_array](http://php.net/manual/de/function.in-array.php) function like this:

```
if ( in_array($template_file, ['page-custom-one.php', 'page-custom-two.php'], TRUE) ) {
  remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'editor' );
}
```

Besides, you should always use strict comparison over loose comparison to prevent unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Strange, I thought something like either of those would do the job but neither have had any effect of the second page?

Comment: Have you tested if the editor gets removed with both template files in a two single if conditions? Or maybe value of `$template_file` is not your expected one?

Comment: Your first answer was correct I have the second file in different folder from the first so for me it's like: "templates/page-custom-two.php".

Thanks

Comment: Ok, glad I could help!